# JMockit mock casting

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I have java code as

```
public void isRequestAuthorized() {
    final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest =
            ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    final String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader("x-api-key");
    boolean result = auth(header);
```

I am trying to perform unit test using jmockit.

```
  @mockit.Mocked
  private HttpServletRequest mockRequest;

  @mockit.Mocked
  private ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes;

  @mockit.Tested
  private transient AuthorizeImpl authorize;

  @Test
  public void test_validRequestAuthorize(){
   // Since getReuestAttributes method is static I mocked it here.
    new MockUp<RequestContextHolder>() {
      public RequestAttributes getRequestAttributes() {
        return requestAttributes;
      }
    };

    new Expectations() {{
      requestAttributes.getRequest(); result = mockRequest;
      mockRequest.getHeader(anyString); result = "api-key";
    }};

    Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(()->authorize.isRequestAuthorized());
```

When I am trying to perform above unit test I am getting this error

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.NullPointerException
at <filepath>
Suppressed: Missing 1 invocation to:
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes#getRequest()
   on mock instance: org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes@45312be2
```

My understanding is that in actual code value returned on `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` is again casted to `ServletRequestAttributes` which I am not able to mock.

Can someone please help me on how to resolve this error? I am new to Jmockit so still learning.

Comment: Can you try mocking “ getRequest()” method as well?

Comment: I did that and while error for `getRequest` method is gone it is now showing error for `getHeader` method.

Answer (score 0):

JMockit can be finicky about Expectations.  I have had good luck solving issues like this by doing something like this:

```
new Expectations(requestAttributes, mockRequest) {{
  requestAttributes.getRequest(); result = mockRequest;
  mockRequest.getHeader(anyString); result = "api-key";
}};
```

For emphasis, I added the mocks as arguments to Expectation.  if that works, and if it does, I'm sure there's an elegant answer why you have to flag those variables for partial-mocking [which is what adding them to the Expectations does] and not just rely on the @Mock annotation.  In any event, I've had good luck doing this.

P.S.  you may not need the 'mockRequest' object in the Expectations.  It likely doesn't hurt to add it, other than it is more test-code clutter.